# Is there any way to reverse or undo the preventExtensions function?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

It is possible to make a non extensible object extensible ?

```js
var obj = {};
Object.preventExtensions(obj);
obj.abc = "abc"; // this line is ignored which is normal
//is there a way to make obj extensible again
```

Comment: On [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) it says "There is no way to make an object extensible again once it has been made non-extensible." Maybe you could reassign the object?

Answer (score 5):

How about a deep clone?

```
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
obj.abc = "abc"; // this line is now OK
```

Is OK in local code but any external references that came with `obj` will no longer point to the newly formed `obj`.

Comment: Also possible: `obj = Object.assign({}, obj);`

Comment: @frot.io that won't deep clone fully see: https://medium.com/@tkssharma/objects-in-javascript-object-assign-deep-copy-64106c9aefab

Answer (score 0):

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions#description) says:

> There is no way to make an object extensible again once it has been made non-extensible.

The easiest way to overcome this situation is to clone the object and assign it to a new variable:

```js
const person = {
  name: "John",
  colors: {
    eyes: 'orange',
    hair: 'blue'
  }
};

Object.preventExtensions(person);
console.log(Object.isExtensible(person)); // false

const extensiblePerson = {...person};
console.log(Object.isExtensible(extensiblePerson)); // true
```

It is important to note that `Object.preventExtensions` only prevents the extension of the top level of the object. In the example above, `person.colors` is still extensible, even though its parent object is not.

```
console.log(Object.isExtensible(person.colors)); // true
console.log(extensiblePerson.colors === person.colors); // true
```